# possible to use jquery to show/hide ajaxcontroltoolkit accordion?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I have an AjaxControlToolkit that I'd like to show or hide based on a dropdown value.

I was able to sort of get it to hide by changing the text of the "ShowLinkButton" control (using a blank "" where I wanted to hide the accordion), but I'd like to hide the accordion itself. (The accordion is clickable even when the text is blank.)

So, here's my jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('#<%= DDStatusList.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        var statusval2 = $("#SampleContent_Tabs_TabPanel3_DDStatusList").val();
        if (statusval2 == 4) {
            $('#<%= ShowLinkButton.ClientID%>').html("Show Accordion");
        }
        else {
            $('#<%= ShowLinkButton.ClientID%>').html("");
        }
    }));
});​
```

I've tried to make both the Accordion's and the LinkButton's visible property = false, and then make it true when the condition is met in the jquery function, but neither strategy seems to work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, all.

I wound up doing this:

```
if ($('#<%= DDStatusList.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                                        var statusval2 = $("#MainContent_Tabs_TabPanel3_DDStatusList").val();
                                        var statusvalcurrent = $("#MainContent_LabelStatusNumber").text();
                                        if (statusval2 == 4 && statusvalcurrent == 4.3) {

                                            $('#<%= status43panel.ClientID%>').show();

                                            //alert("show");
                                        }
                                        else {

                                            $('#<%= status43panel.ClientID%>').hide();

                                            //alert("hide");
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$(function() {
    if ($('#<%= DDStatusList.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        var statusval2 = $("#SampleContent_Tabs_TabPanel3_DDStatusList").val();
        if (statusval2 == 4) {
            $('#<%= ShowLinkButton.ClientID%>').html("Show Accordion");
            //$find('<%= MyAccordion.ClientID%>').show();
            showAccordionPane('<%= MyAccordion.ClientID%>', 1);
        }
        else {
            $('#<%= ShowLinkButton.ClientID%>').html("");
            //$find('<%= MyAccordion.ClientID%>').hide();
            hideAccordionPane('<%= MyAccordion.ClientID%>', 1);
        }
    }));
});

// hides pane 1
function hideAccordionPane(AccordionCtrl, paneno) {
    $find(AccordionCtrl).get_Pane(paneno).header.style.display = "none";
    $find(AccordionCtrl).get_Pane(paneno).content.style.display = "none";
}​

// shows pane 1
function showAccordionPane(AccordionCtrl, paneno) {
    $find(AccordionCtrl).get_Pane(paneno).header.style.display = "block";
    $find(AccordionCtrl).get_Pane(paneno).content.style.display = "block";
}​
```

Comment: just did, but I get an error on the find... (changed "MyAccordion" to match the actual control)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('<%= MyAccordion.ClientID%>').AccordionBehavior.set_SelectedIndex(2)// expand panel nr.3
// index starts from 0 (number of panel ) if close  set it -1
```

or jquery

```
$('#<%= MyAccordion.ClientID %>').get(0).AccordionBehavior.set_SelectedIndex(2)

 $('#<%= MyAccordion.ClientID %>').get(0).set_TransitionDuration(1000) //set timeout for collapse in ms.
```

hide panel with content

```
   document.getElementById('ctl00_SampleContent_MyAccordion').AccordionBehavior.get_Pane(0).content.style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('ctl00_SampleContent_MyAccordion').AccordionBehavior.get_Pane(0).header.style.display='none';
```

Javscript was tested here http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx in debug console of  chrome